# how to use react route to not rerender the entire app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using an `App` Component to hold all the route so it looks like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { signedIn: false };
  handleSignedIn = () => {
    this.setState({ signedIn: true });
  };
  render() {
    <Router>
      <Route>Header</Route>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        {...otherRoutes}
      </Switch>
      <Route>Footer</Route>
    </Router>;
  }
}
```

then in one of the routes, I have something like this

```
<NavLink to="/">
  Home
</NavLink>
```

However, i find that clicking on this `NavLink` rerenders `App` and set `signedIn` to `false`, what's the right/better way to navigate around this.

-- updated routes for more details

Basically i am expecting the `<App>` itself not to rerender, but the `<Router>` should.

Comment: What's your `otherRoutes` look like? Also, I see you're not using any `path` along those `Route`s which means they always match and will be re-rendered.

Comment: @norbertpy updated

Answer (score 0):

Returning to App.js means signedIn is reset to false, since the default state is false. Refreshing the page will also rerender App.js and reset it back to false.

You need some way of checking if the user is logged in already. One way of doing so is by storing a token client-side after logging in, and checking if the token is present when a component loads.

You can possibly store the token in localStorage, and then whenever App.js mounts do something like componentDidMount -> checkToken() -> setState({signedIn: true})

Comment: that's probably a separate concern (store token and check token). wouldn't you think a rerouting by navlink should left the parent `App` alone?